# Flutter: rendering an UI from JSON and store / map data dynamic

Tags: json, data-binding, flutter, data-mapping

I want to render a UI from a jSON string that has multiple layers.
The user should be able to enter data, which will then be stored and shared, without the overhead of the jSON Render Structure.
However, the assignment of the data must be possible.

The app renders a template from a multidimensional json string that can capture metrics (user inputs). The measured data are entered via text fields by the user.

There are different windows in the app, which are rendered from different json UI-render-files.
The stored algorithms in the windows at the Frontend differ.

The following should be possible:
All windows are created with different jSON strings (works with build_value now).
The user's input is saved. (Currently only works by saving the render json string with the data under a different name (with Package: Shared Preferences)).

The data entered by the user is copied from one window to the other window. (Data Binding / Data Mapping)

The data entered by the user will be sent to a backend.

I only have the idea to use id's in the render json, which allow a mapping.
Are there better solutions?

Saving the entered data is possible by saving the whole jSON - String with an other name.
The goal is to map the data.

It should also be possible for the user to insert another object for the measurement data acquisition at the client / device. The entered data must also be saved.

Comment: Did you try anything? Could you provide some code? Fetching data from a JSON is simple on Flutter and you have documentation for it: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/background-parsing

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a REST API. Then you would use a frontend framework like angular or react to take user input.

I could build this with a .net core web api with sql db as the backend. this would be a web service (REST API solution) on the backend of your solution.

Next I would integrate Swagger with dependency injection and add authentication.

now its time to create the front end that will use your tested Web Service.

you would have 1 side of your SPA POST new JSON to the Web service in a form.

you would have the other side GET the new record as a new tab with pagination or in a table with pagination.

This would be a good PoC for your idea and will let you learn the parts of the solutions architecture in your language of choice. the "design" would be the same no matter what language your choice.

backend web service can be done in a flask and with a MySQL DB. or with any other combo you have skills with.

the Frontend could be done in knockout.js, making it a little easier to learn than angular or react.

Please create new questions when you choose your software design. I would love to give answers for each:)

I would love to level up with you! ;)